# powershell system.object array to String

Tags: powershell

I'm using the below code to pull the IP Address of the User (supplied at beginning of code) that had a failed logon attempt.  The code works, but when I use GetType() the variable $ipp, it comes back as a Name is Object[] Base Type is System.Array  I need this variable to be a string (I'm looking for the IP in a text file and removing it if it's found).

```
$ipp = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';Id=4625;StartTime=$hours} | 
    Where-Object {$_.Properties[5].Value -like "*$userName*"} | 
    Select-Object -First 1 {$_.Properties[19].value}
```

I'm using PowerShell 5

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: Well, first, users don't have IP addresses. I understand that you are trying to get the IP address of the machine that the user was on. Second remove the pipe to Format-Table as a start.

Comment: Removing the pipe to Format-Table changes the GetType result to be:
Name is PSCustomObject and BaseType is System.Object

In my testing I have the following code below the code above:

if($ipp -eq "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"){"Yes"}else{"No"}
$ipp and my "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx" are the same, but powershell doesn't see them as equal.

Comment: Edit your question: 1. Remove Format-Table, 2. Post results of `$ipp|gm`

Comment: Result of $ipp | gm is blank, so is the value of $ipp with the pipe to format table

Answer (score 0):

**Pre-warning:** This will probably be your best bet for a full array of each bit of information from the bad attempt/lockout event. You can assign each object to a variable easily, check out the last line for some of the property names I use when checking locked accounts.

I have been doing a lot of this sort of stuff at work lately and came across a nice Microsoft demo. I unashamedly stole their script, works like a charm.

I hoped you were connecting to a domain controller but it looks like that event ID is for a bad attempt on the clients machine, not the DC.

Changed it a bit so you can slot it in after you have defined your $userName and left the Microsoft comments. Just check out line 87/88 as you may need to complete that if you encounter errors with your DC.

```
# Set up the lockout report
$report = @()

# Pick the DCs to crawl
$DCs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * |
    Select-Object HostName, IPv4Address, Site, OperatingSystem, OperationMasterRoles |
    Out-Gridview -Title "Select the DCs to query" -PassThru |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty HostName

# Find the lockout stats for that user on all selected DCs
ForEach ($DC in $DCs) {
    $report += Get-ADUser $userName -Server $DC -ErrorAction Continue `
        -Properties cn, LockedOut, pwdLastSet, badPwdCount, badPasswordTime, lastLogon, lastLogoff, lastLogonTimeStamp, whenCreated, whenChanged | `
        Select-Object *, @{name='DC';expression={$DC}} 
}

$DCs = $report |
    Select-Object `
        DC, `
        cn, `
        LockedOut, `
        pwdLastSet, `
        @{name='pwdLastSetConverted';expression={[datetime]::fromFileTime($_.pwdlastset)}}, `
        badPwdCount,
        badPasswordTime, `
        @{name='badPasswordTimeConverted';expression={[datetime]::fromFileTime($_.badPasswordTime)}}, `
        lastLogon, `
        @{name='lastLogonConverted';expression={[datetime]::fromFileTime($_.lastLogon)}}, `
        lastLogoff, `
        @{name='lastLogoffConverted';expression={[datetime]::fromFileTime($_.lastLogoff)}}, `
        lastLogonTimeStamp, `
        @{name='lastLogonTimestampConverted';expression={[datetime]::fromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}}, `
        whenCreated, `
        whenChanged |
    Out-GridView -Title "Select the DC to query event logs for lockouts" -PassThru

# Filter generated using Event Viewer GUI Custom View
# Logon/Lockout events in the last 24 hours
[xml]$xmlFilter = @"
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[(EventID=529 or EventID=644 or EventID=675 or EventID=676 or EventID=681 or EventID=4740 or EventID=4771) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 86400000]]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
"@


$Events = @()
ForEach ($DC in $DCs) {

    "Getting events from $($DC.DC)"

    # Must enable the firewall rule for remote EventLog management - CHECK WITH YOUR IT TEAM, THIS MAY BREACH YOUR COMPANY SECURITY POLICY
    # Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DC.DC -ScriptBlock {Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *eventlog* | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq 'False'} | Enable-NetFirewallRule -Verbose}

    ### Filter for the userID in the event message properties
    $Events += Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $DC.DC -FilterXML $xmlFilter
}

ForEach ($Event in $Events) {
    # Convert the event to XML
    $eventXML = [xml]$Event.ToXml()
    # Iterate through each one of the XML message properties
    For ($i=0; $i -lt $eventXML.Event.EventData.Data.Count; $i++) {
        # Append these as object properties
        Add-Member -InputObject $Event -MemberType NoteProperty -Force `
            -Name  $eventXML.Event.EventData.Data[$i].name `
            -Value $eventXML.Event.EventData.Data[$i].'#text'
    }
}

# View the lockout details
$Events | Where-Object {$_.TargetUserName -eq $userName} | Select-Object TargetUserName, IPAddress, MachineName, TimeCreated | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Drew,
Thanks for sharing, but all of that is completely over my head.  We have a single 2016 Server running as both the DC and the RDS server.  I've created my own IP Blocker (which works great) and was trying to write a script to easily remove a blocked IP (when the IP is blocked, it's written to a text file, which in turn is used to create the Firewall Rules) of a verified user.  The script would remove the IP from the text file then delete/recreate the Firewall Rule.  I will dig into the code you provided, I think I can learn a few things from it.

Comment: when I add | out-string then I "look" at $ipp is reads:
$_.Properties[19].value
--------------------
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx

(I use x's instead the actual ip)

Comment: got this working by using the following:  

`$ip = $ipp.Trim()`